# XML against XSD not valid

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I generated this xml file by marshalling it and then i want to unmarshall it by validating it to its schema. Why is this xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProjectConfiguration xmlns="http://ereg.egov.bg/segment/0009-900001">
    <CreationTime>2012-08-30T15:32:06.712+03:00</CreationTime>
    <Applications>
        <Application>
            <Version>1.0</Version>
            <CreationTime>2012-08-30T15:32:06.712+03:00</CreationTime>
            <FileName>ROSAppl-37</FileName>
        </Application>
    </Applications>
</ProjectConfiguration>
```

not a valid xml agains this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema 
targetNamespace="http://www.bulsi.bg/egov/ProjectConfiguration"
xmlns="http://www.bulsi.bg/egov/ProjectConfiguration"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>

<xsd:element name="ProjectConfiguration" type="ProjectConfigurationType" />

<xsd:complexType name="ProjectConfigurationType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="bg">Конфигурация на проекта</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>

    <xsd:sequence>  
        <xsd:element name="CreationTime" type="xsd:dateTime">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="bg">Време на създаване</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>

        <xsd:element name="Applications" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="bg">Заявления</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Application" type="ApplicationType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>                      
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="ApplicationType" >
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="bg">Данни за заявление за вписване</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>

    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Version" type="xsd:string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="bg">Версия на заявлението</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>

        <xsd:element name="CreationTime" type="xsd:dateTime">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="bg">Време на създаване</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>

        <xsd:element name="FileName" type="xsd:string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="bg">Име на файл, в който е заявлението. Връзка между конфигурационни параметри и заявлението като файл</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>  
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

This is the error : **Cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'ProjectConfiguration'.. Line '2', Column '71'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your Xml instance: `xmlns="http://ereg.egov.bg/segment/0009-900001"`
- Your Xml schema: `targetNamespace="http://www.bulsi.bg/egov/ProjectConfiguration"`

These URIs should match.

Otherwise, the `<ProjectConfiguration>` element from your Xml document will be assumed to belong to the `http://ereg.egov.bg/segment/0009-900001` namespace, which is not defined in your schema.

Comment: okay that fixed the ProjectConfiguration problem but now i get this error : Cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid Content Was Found Starting With Element 'CreationTime'. One Of '{CreationTime}' Is Expected.. Line '3', Column '19'.